# Pattern for cubed values

Tags: exponentiation, pattern-recognition

[We now have a pattern for squared values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946752/is-there-a-fast-pattern-to-get-squared-values), but what about cubed ones? Basically it is $ x^3 $.

I wasn't able to find a precise pattern that's similar to my answer on the linked post, as the result contains:

```
1^3 = 1
7
2^3 = 8
19
3^3 = 27
37
4^3 = 64
61
5^3 = 125
91
6^3 = 216
127
7^3 = 343
169
8^3 = 512
217
9^3 = 729
271
10^3 = 1,000
```

And I could barely make an equation basing it.

Without the help of a calculator, can I get the cubed values via patterns?

Comment: With finite differences, of course. Try looking at the difference between 1 and 8, 8, and 27, etc. Then look at the difference between those values. Then those values. Keep going, you will eventually reach a constant. Another way to do this is to expand $(ax+by)^3$. In addition, you can memorize $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)\implies x^3=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+1$, and use the thing you found with squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the  difference between consecutive cubes is

$$x^3-(x-1)^3= x^3-x^3+3x^2-3x+1=3x(x-1)+1$$

Three times the product of the bases plus one.

Comment: I've been making a list for all these patterns. Thank you for the simple equation.